# How do you pass an image from Wand to Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, wand

I'm trying to do some OCR work. `pytesseract` doesn't play nicely with Wand images, but Python Image Library can't do some of the image transforms I want to do that make the OCR perform better.

At the moment, I'm using Wand to open the image, do my ImageMagick transforms, then saving it to a temp file which I then open using Pillow and pass to pytesseract. Is there a way I can do this without using a temp file? I'd like to be able to handle this all using functions that can't potentially foul each other up if they're running in parallel.

Comment: Instead of a temp file - can you save it to a `BytesIO` object instead and and pass that as the input to pillow?

Comment: I tried that, but I keep getting "BlobError: zero-length blob not permitted `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/348"

Comment: Can you show the code you're using for that in your question then? (eg - creating the BytesIO - saving to it, then trying to read from it?)

Comment: Actually, this does work. It fails the other way, which I'd like to do but don't need; that code is: `In [110]: with io.BytesIO() as output:
⁋    region.save(output, format=i.format)
⁋     wimg = WandImage(blob=output)`

Comment: You've already solved it then?

Comment: Seems so. Though I would like to know how to go the other direction as well, if it's possible.

Comment: Look at how to make wand write to a bytesio object, then use pillow to read it? It's going to be very similar to what you're doing now but in reverse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184049/discussion-between-futuraprime-and-jon-clements).

Answer (score 0):

To go from Wand to PIL, you can use `io.BytesIO`:

```
with io.BytesIO() as transfer:
    with WandImage(filename=fpath) as img:
        img.unsharp_mask(radius=2, sigma=0, amount=75, threshold=2)
        img.level(black=150/255, white=202/255, gamma=2.1)
        img.save(transfer)

    with Image.open(transfer) as img:
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
        with open('./%s/%s-tess4.txt' % (outputdir, fname), 'w+') as f:
            f.write(text)
```

This does not seem to work to move a PIL image into Wand, however.

Comment: In upcoming Wand 0.53, you can transfer via numpy array.